# How can I install CyanogenMod on my HTC Magic?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-magic

How can I install CyanogenMod on my HTC Magic? Is there a tutorial or guide for this that I can follow?
Sorry guys..if you feel that I was asking a silly question..!
my intention was to have a brief summary about the dos and donts for getting cynogenmod in HTC phones...

Comment: You can find lots of guides and tutorials regarding this. Just a simple Google Search revealed [this](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/HTC_Magic_(32B):_Rooting)

Answer (score 6):

There already is a guide for install on the [CyanogenMod forums](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/278-installation-support-line-cyanogenmod-for-dreammagic/) and a [main page](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices/htc-magic) for the device which contains download links and other general info.

Comment: As of note, the HTC Magic only supports CyanogenMod 6. (Or earlier, which you don't really want.)